# Ingresar datos aun DropDownList desde una consulta sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema a la hora de ingresar datos en un DropDownList, pues tengo el código, pero a la hora de iniciar sesión en la página como usuario no me muestra información en el DropDownList y no se a qué se deba, pues eh revisado mi consulta y esta bien. Dejo el código esperando puedan ayudarme.

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Int32 iCodigo;
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null) //valido el usuario ingresado
        {
            using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(Conexión))
            {
                using (OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SlpCode FROM Vendedores Where SlpName = '"+Request.QueryString["id"]+"'", cn)) //selecciono el ID del usuario que ingreso, pues necesito validarlo en la consulta siguiente
                {
                    iCodigo = Convert.ToInt32(cm.ExecuteReader()); //asigno una variable de tipo Int al query para llamarla después.

                }
            }
               OdbcConnection cnx = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=Conexion server;uid=sa;pwd=alimentaria");
               OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT A.CardCode, A.CardName, B.SlpName FROM Clientes A INNER JOIN Vendedores B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode Where A.SlpCode = " + iCodigo+ " AND LicTradNum ='XAXX010101000'", cnx); 
               OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
               DataTable ds = new DataTable();
               da.Fill(ds);
               this.VENTA.DataSource = ds;
            this.VENTA.DataValueField = "CardName";
               this.VENTA.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Cuando haces depuración que valor muestra Request.QueryString["id"]?? y la variable iCodigo con que valor queda??

Comment: Muestra el nombre del usuario que ingresó a la plataforma, lo tengo en la página Login como, la variable iCodigo pretendo que quede con el ID del usuario (SlpCode) en el query

Comment: Ok, y en este momento iCodigo con que valor está quedando, si se esta asignando el código correcto?. Por que si en esa asignación estas esperando un solo dato es mejor que utilices ExecuteScalar. `iCodigo = Convert.ToInt32(cm.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: Si, lo eh utilizado de esa forma también, el problema lo tengo en cuando intento mostrar los datos en el DropDownList

Comment: Esta bien....entonces verifica si te hace falta asignar la propiedad DataTextField al DropDownList. `this.VENTA.DataTextField = "CardName"`

Comment: Disculpa, pero de igual manera me sigue sin mostrar nada. ¿Es correcto llamar solo "CardName" cuando en el query tengo "A.CardName" por utilizar dos tablas?

Comment: No importa el nombre, "CardName" debería funcionar. Deberias revisar en depuración que datos te esta almacenando la variable ds. Para determinar si es problema de la consulta o problema del control DropDownList

Comment: Perdona mi pregunta, pero como hago eso? haha:/

Comment: Dale un vistazo a este video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOWq6Lwdq1I